# Warning: This declaration shadows an existing declaration with a Struct

Tags: solidity, compilation, smart-contract

I 'm looking for a way to clean my compile warning, i have a `Warning: This declaration shadows an existing declaration.` on the function below.
The Transaction in the return is a `Struct` compose with id, sender,receiver etc...
I don't know how i could refactor my code, any idea ?

[image: the function]
[image: The compile warning]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Whenever you specify the return element in `returns()` with a variable name, you don't really need to create the variable again in the function. What you are doing here is expecting a variable, named `transaction`, of type `Transaction memory`, to be returned from the function. And again, you are re-declaring the variable, which gives a shadow warning.

I would recommend to just remove the variable name from the `returns()` part. Just keep it

```
returns(Transaction memory) {}
```

Also, if you are working with `pure` and `view` functions, you can use `memory` instead of `storage` since you are not going to update your global structs.

Comment: Nice thanks you very much
If i well understand i could as well write `Transaction memory transaction` in my returns and  only `transaction = transactions[_transactionId]`in my function

Comment: Yes, that works too, and you are welcome. Please accept the answer if it helped you. :)

Comment: You mean "accept the answer" i have to click somewhere :) i'm new on the platform

Comment: That's alright. I was confused in the beginning too. It is a small tick below the upvotes. :)